# Incooperation of a changing date into an e-mail text via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, email, text

I have got text attached to an email.  My aim is to incorporate the date, which states in a worksheet in the range `E2` into the text (e.g. as illustrated below `Juni 2018`).

```
datDate=WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("Description").Range("E2"))

strText="<span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:""Arial"",""sans-serif"";" & _
    "color:black'>Hello,<br><br>please find attached the Report " & _
    "for ***Juni 2018***.<br><br>"
```

Comment: thank you. just corrected. And i got already a negative vote. No idea why

Comment: This site is very picky about formatting and clarity when posting questions. Stack Overflow gets a new question posted about every 13 seconds and not every one can be answered; people like to see that effort was made both into trying to solve the problem yourself, and into making the question as clear as possible. (see "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]** plus [these tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) from the site's top user.)   That said, it would be nice if people could leave a comment when they down-vote - I know that's frustrating but it happens.

Comment: I  have really put effort into the question. And i dont knnow how it could be formulated any better? A pre-check of the questions before they go live would be a nice feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `datDate` is correctly holding the date in question, you could use:

```
strText = "<span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:""Arial"",""sans-serif"";" & _
    "color:black'>Hello,<br><br>please find attached the Report " & _
    "via ***" & Format(datDate, "MMMM yyyy") & "***.<br><br>"
```

Also, I know you didn't ask for grammar advice but I figured I'd point out that [*"via"*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/via) is not the correct word in this case. (*"Via"* would be used to name a location that an item travelled through on the way to it's destination.)

*`for`* is the word I would use.  :)

Comment: cheers, the right code is:                                                                                 strText = "<span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:""Arial"",""sans-serif"";" & _
    "color:black'>Hello,<br><br>please find attached the Report for " & Format(datDatum, "YYYYMMDD") & ".<br><br>"